# How Angular2 inject variable inside directive constructor

Tags: angular

I am newbie user of Angular2.
I saw these code in the Doc

```
@Directive({ selector: '[myHighlight]' })
export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
       renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', 'yellow');
    }
}
```

I know how to use Directive、 ElementRef and Renderer.
My question is how angular2 inject these variables in constructor method?
Why I can use `this.el` after class constructed?
What is the mechanism or design pattern behind these scenario?
Base on my little coding experience, I have no idea how to do this if someone ask me to implement this mechanism.

Thank you for your patience.

- Not native english speaker, sorry for poor english.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript for Angular 2?

Comment: yes, I am using TS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called `Dependency Injection`.
See the official docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html

This is done automatically, you don't have to care about that!
Angular2 only needs to know those types you are trying to instantiate in your `constructor`.

You could even create your own `Service` and 'mark' it as `@Injectable()` with that decorator.

See docs for creating a custom service: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Answer (score 0):

Thy this:

```
 constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {}
```

Make sure that you imported all the necessary things:

```
import {Directive, Inject, ElementRef, Renderer} from '@angular/core'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   However, I understand how to use this and the code is working. 
My question is : If I need to implement this inject mechanism, how can I do from pure JS(or TS)  
Why can I only declare variable and type and then I can use them.    
I cannot figure out how Angular2 inside mechanism.
Sorry for misleading question